# PrintWriter does not print inside if

Tags: java, file, output

I'm having some trouble with this `PrintWriter`, it is working outside the `for` loop and it does print "Test1" and "Test2" but it doesn't print "example 1" inside the `If`

The line of code is executed as I checked it with the debugger

```
 File file = new File ("output.txt");
 FileWriter wri;
 try {
    wri = new FileWriter(file);

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(wri);
    writer.println("Test1");

    boolean result=false;

    for(i=0;i<this.lung;i++){

       for(j=0;j<this.lung;j++){

            if(wordToFind.charAt(0)==mat[i][j]){

                if((i>=wordLength-1)&&(results!=true))
                    if (wordToFind.charAt(1)==mat[i-1][j])
                        if(result=continue(i,j,i-1,j,1))
                            writer.println("example 1");
                  /*Same if as the above but with differente parameters are down here*/
                  }
             } 
         }
      }
      writer.print("Test2");
      writer.close();

  } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + e);
 }
```

Comment: How did you check that the line is actually executed?

Comment: You would get a compilation failure because of using `continue` as a method name!

Comment: I've changed the word to "continue" for the purpose of posting it on StackOverflow as the original code is in another "language", so it shouldn't be the problem

Comment: In that case it would be appropriate to show that `continue(...)` method

Comment: The method is working because if I try to output it with a `System.out.println` it does print it in the console.

Comment: @AlessandroCifani method working doesn`t means that it will be returning a true value which can be assigned to `result` to make `if` body execute

Comment: It is indeed returning a `true` value and the code is being executed, I double checked it with the Eclipse debugger!

Comment: Then I dont think there is any problem with your code, (assuming that `continue(...)` method returns `true`.

Comment: Thank you anyway but still the string is not yet printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these two `results` / `result` same variable , if it is then try changing the first one to `result`;

// assumed 'coz I didnt found any `results` `boolean` variable in your code

```
if((i>=wordLength-1)&&(results!=true))  // results -> result
                    if (wordToFind.charAt(1)==mat[i-1][j])
                        if(result=continue(i,j,i-1,j,1)) 
                            writer.println("example 1");
```